# how to force link color to be blue not purple in PHP

Tags: php

I am using php and I have some `<a>` tags. I want if I click some `<a>` to "not change the link color to purple" just keep it as blue. How can I do that?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type=”text/css”>
a:visited, a:link, a:hover  {
    font-family : Verdana, Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color           : blue;
}

a:visited, a:link {
   text-decoration : none;
   color           : blue;
}

a:hover  {
    color           : blue;
    text-decoration : underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<td><a href=data/$jobid.blast$page.html#$element[1]$element[2] target='_blank'>$element[3]</a></td>";
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with this, it is a CSS/HTML domain

Comment: I guess you will be needing the `:visited` class

Comment: This is failing you `<style type=”text/css”>` for one thing. That's if that's your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
a { color:blue } /* Globally */

/* Each state */

a:visited { text-decoration: none; color:blue; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; color:blue; }
```

Comment: could you please give me the area? where to put this style? inside head of php file?

Comment: This should be in your css file if you have attached it.

Answer (score 0):

That is css issue, not php.

You need something like:

```
a:visited {
    color: blue;
}
```